# how nova add private key to VM on creating instances

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

I want to know the backend flow how nova while launching any instance, add private key to VM. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about SSH keys, you add the public key to the instance's admin account, not the private key.

It is done by cloud-init.  What typically happens is that Openstack populates the metadata service for the instance with a "vendor data" JSON object which includes the public key.   The instance can retrieve this via a link-local IP address.

When the instance gets to the appropriate point in system startup, it runs the cloud-init job.  This will do various initialization tasks depending on the cloud-init configuration files in your image.  One of the things it will typically do is to create the admin account, and write (or append) the public key in the vendor data to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

For more information, see the [cloud-init documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), the Openstack documentation for [building an Ubuntu image](https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/ubuntu-image.html).